# c++11: Why a const reference vector cannot be traversed?

Tags: c++, vector, reference, constants

The case is what below puts:

```
void func(const std::vector<std::string>& vec){
  for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = vec.begin();it != vec.end();it++){
    //TODO
  }
}
```

My IDE report error :

```
error: conversion from ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >}’ requested
```

It seems like type of the iterator I defined is not consist with that of reference variable vec.begin(). For the sake of protection of the vector referenced, I add the keyword **const**, but I cannot figure it out. Did I miss any essentials of c++? Any suggestions would be much appreciated=)

Comment: const_iterator, or use auto

Comment: No  I mean `std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator`

Comment: okay, I got it, much appreciated for that.=)